# await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules as it is in top level body

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to create a SupaDB client for Steam, [more info](https://www.supadb.dev/steam). When I check the website console, I get the following error message, even when `node file.js` is used, same error is being given. Which the error is:

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

As the info provided, the error also includes that the line where the error occurs is line **8**...

**Full log:**

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase.from("steam").select("*")
                        ^^^^^
```

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
> at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

```js
const supabase = createClient("https://gqkuommdmfzmwkzdewma.supabase.co", 
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Imdxa3VvbW1kbWZ6bXdremRld21hIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDkyNjQyNTIsImV4cCI6MTk2NDg0MDI1Mn0.iF651HDhqynAQRlG8T6wFS3ZEx4dqxHiEiguc0m7-zI", {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzZWNyZXQiOiI3MjU5YTg2ZDVlMTE1YTM2ODRjMjdlNGUiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTAyODg1MzJ9.43EriTTwaDLeepFTbRoZXJksqCtIrjMZ-yHHMDuK0_4"
  }
})

const { data, error } = await supabase.from("steam").select("*")

    if (error) {
        console.log('Error occurred:', error)
        }
    else {
        console.log(data)
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- link CSS and JavaScript to HTML -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using the latest version of NodeJS which supports top level await, you cannot use `await` outside of an async function.

You can work around this by encapsulating your code in an IIFE function:

```
(async() => {
  // your code using await goes here
  const supabase = createClient("https://gqkuommdmfzmwkzdewma.supabase.co", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Imdxa3VvbW1kbWZ6bXdremRld21hIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDkyNjQyNTIsImV4cCI6MTk2NDg0MDI1Mn0.iF651HDhqynAQRlG8T6wFS3ZEx4dqxHiEiguc0m7-zI", {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzZWNyZXQiOiI3MjU5YTg2ZDVlMTE1YTM2ODRjMjdlNGUiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTAyODg1MzJ9.43EriTTwaDLeepFTbRoZXJksqCtIrjMZ-yHHMDuK0_4"
  }
})

const { data, error } = await supabase.from("steam").select("*")
    if (error)
      console.log('Error occurred:', error)
    else
      console.log(data)
})()
```

Comment: Great and simple, specially for those like me who don't have the option of changing legacy code much. Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "type":"module" at your package.json file and that will allow you to use top level await

Answer (score 0):

> await is only valid in async functions

This means you can only use `await` if your function is `async`. Right now you are just using keyword `await` without `async`

```js
let dummyMethod = async () => {
    const supabase = createClient("https://gqkuommdmfzmwkzdewma.supabase.co",
        "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Imdxa3VvbW1kbWZ6bXdremRld21hIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDkyNjQyNTIsImV4cCI6MTk2NDg0MDI1Mn0.iF651HDhqynAQRlG8T6wFS3ZEx4dqxHiEiguc0m7-zI", {
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzZWNyZXQiOiI3MjU5YTg2ZDVlMTE1YTM2ODRjMjdlNGUiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTAyODg1MzJ9.43EriTTwaDLeepFTbRoZXJksqCtIrjMZ-yHHMDuK0_4"
            }
        })

    const {
        data,
        error
    } = await supabase.from("steam").select("*")

    if (error) {
        console.log('Error occurred:', error)
    } else {
        console.log(data)
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- link CSS and JavaScript to HTML -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Now you will not get an error message. Since we are wrapping your `await` in `async` method.

Nothing will log to console, since I'm not calling the `dummyMethod`.